# WooCommerce hide all products of a certain category if not loggedin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been searching everywhere to find this answer and have even downloaded multiple plugins, all of which haven't worked.

Is there a way to achieve this using PHP?

I have this code:

```
 <?php if( !is_user_logged_in() && get_field('___unit_price') ): ?>
 <p>Unit Price: $<?php the_field('___unit_price'); ?></p>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Which seems to work for specific products but does not work for an entire category, any help would be much appeciated

Comment: are you looking to "hide all product" as you said in the Title or to hide only the price field ??
If you want to "hide all product of a certain category", please have a look at my answer.

Comment: hide all product of a certain category for users who are not logged in.

i'll check out the below solutions and see which works, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following in **function.php** of your *child-theme:*

```
/* hide YOURCATEGORY category for not loggedin user
===================================================*/

    if ( !is_user_logged_in()) {
        function custom_pre_get_posts_q( $q ) {

            $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

            $tax_query[] = array(
                   'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                   'field' => 'slug',
                   'terms' => array( 'YOURCATEGORY' ), // Don't display products in the composite category on the shop page.
                   'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            );


            $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

        }
        add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_q' );
    }
```

Do not forget to replace 'YOURCATEGORY' by the slug of the category you want to hide.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('init', 'bbloomer_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in');

function bbloomer_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in() { 
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {       
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );  
 add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_print_login_to_see', 31 );
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_print_login_to_see', 11 );
}
}

function bbloomer_print_login_to_see() {
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">' . __('Login to see prices', 'theme_name') . '</a>';
}
```

add this into your functions.php files for more check this link 
https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-hide-price-add-cart-logged-users/

Comment: hey mate, appreciate this but where would I choose the category that is hidden from the user?